# Is it possible to stick a nextjs application into drupal? Would one go about doing this with a custom module or nginx? I want same base url as drupal

Tags: nginx, drupal, devops, next.js13

Given an already completed nextjs application, if I wanted to stick this into drupal on the same base url as an internal drupal app how would I go about doing that?  For instance the drupal site would be https://example.com and the nextjs application would be found at https://example.com/nextjs-app.  I imagine it is possible to do this with nginx and/or using a reverse proxy in some way. I am not sure if it is possible to embed a nextjs application into drupal in some way.  I know there is a nextjs for drupal app, but am not sure if it can do this specifically.  Notably, I am not looking for a way to put the nextjs app on https://hello.example.com/nextjs-app.  The domain I am hoping will be similar to what I specified. I'm more just looking for which route is possible in terms of sticking the nextjs app  on that url.

I have briefly looked into the nextjs for drupal app but I don't think that would solve the problem that my drupal url will be the one taking the route, whereas the nextjs app will not be able to get there without some extra configuring. I am also interested to see if blacklisting certain drupal paths and then pointing to the app would work.